# How to Assign A Custom PowerPoint Template in VBA

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

I'm writing a macro in Excel that creates a new PowerPoint and inserts text from the workbook to specific areas of the slides. I've already created custom layouts for the 5 slides but don't know where to save the PowerPoint template file and how to reference it after the fact using VBA?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the current templates folder in one of three ways:

1. Via the UI by clicking **File** / **Save As** and selecting the .potx file type. This will yield the folder in the format C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates and you can generate this in VBA by using:

   sPath = Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Templates"
2. Via the UI by clicking **File** / **Options** / **Save** and looking for the field **Default Personal Templates Location**
3. Via programming methods to extract the path from the Windows Registry using Windows API calls as per [this Microsoft article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/145679).

Once you know where the template file is, you can use this method to apply it:

```
ActivePresentation.ApplyTemplate [filename]
```

Comment: By the way, this is the registry value for PowerPoint 2013: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\PowerPoint\Options\PersonalTemplates

Comment: Thanks for the reply, JamieG. I'm running PowerPoint 2010. Still having trouble getting the newly created PowerPoint to use the template that I saved in the appropriate folder: C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates .

Comment: What appears to be the problem? Any specific code you can share?